# strtotime in PHP for dd MM yyyy

Tags: php, strtotime

While trying:

```
echo "<br />".$opening_time = "02 May 2019 - 03:10";
echo "<br />".$closing_time = "12 May 2019 - 13:40";
echo "<br />".$string_opening_time = strtotime($opening_time);
echo "<br />".$string_closing_time = strtotime($closing_time);
echo "<br />".$diffrence_time = $string_closing_time - $string_opening_time;
```

The results are:

> 02 May 2019 - 03:10 12
>
> May 2019 - 13:40
>
> //2 blank lines
>
> 0

Why it is blank when I convert it to strtotime?

Comment: Probably because that's not a known date time format, so strtotime is returning false. Might be easier to use [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), then call `format`, (is my opinion).

Comment: https://php.net/datetime.formats.date

Comment: while "02 May 2019" is a correct input for strtotime function "02 May 2019 - 03:10" is not

Comment: and what's your actual question?

Comment: @jeprubio so, what can I do so that it is converted to `strtotime`? User will input *02 May 2019 - 03:10*, no other option from their side..

Comment: @treyBake actual question: Why it is blank when I convert it to `strtotime`?

Comment: @BabaluPandey have a look at `DateTime::createFromFormat` or `date_create_from_format` methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format `d M Y - H:i` is not recognized, but you can recreate it as a DateTime object if you know what format it will be in using `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.

Create two DateTime objects and use the `diff()` method on them, that will give you the difference.

```php
$opening_time = "02 May 2019 - 03:10";
$closing_time = "12 May 2019 - 13:40";

$open = DateTime::createFromFormat("d M Y - H:i", $opening_time);
$close = DateTime::createFromFormat("d M Y - H:i", $closing_time );
$diff = $open->diff($close);

echo $opening_time."<br />\n";
echo $closing_time."<br />\n";
echo $diff->d." days ".$diff->h." hours ".$diff->m." minutes ";
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/3pKr4

If you need the difference in seconds, use the `getTimestamp()` methods.

```php
$open = DateTime::createFromFormat("d M Y - H:i", $opening_time);
$close = DateTime::createFromFormat("d M Y - H:i", $closing_time );
$diff = $close->getTimestamp() - $open->getTimestamp();

echo $opening_time."<br />\n";
echo $closing_time."<br />\n";
echo $diff;
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/ZG5LJ

Comment: I need the difference only in seconds

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: It worked! But another issue; I am storing `$opening_time` to MySQL database as *type*: ***datetime***. It says: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '01 May 2019 - 08:25' for column 'Opening_Time'`

Comment: Insert it with the proper format. `$open->format("Y-m-d")`

Comment: This will only insert date, what about time?

Comment: Then add that format too, they're only strings that act like you tell them to. `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: Can you please suggest any best code beautifier? (My page has php,html, javascript)

Comment: Also, what to do if I want to change `2019-05-08 16:40:00` to  *08 May 2019 - 14:40*

Comment: Then you go the other way around.. `$date = new DateTime("2019-05-08 16:40:00")` (that is a valid date-format) then `echo $date->format("d M y - H:i");`.